# How to avoid repetitious SVG code, but without shadow DOM problems caused by defs/symbol/use?

Tags: html, css, svg, shadow-dom

I'm using the following SVG to create two signal level meters that look like this:

[image]

```html
        <svg id="outdoor-meter" class="svg-flow" svg-flow="current-temp,dx=-5,dy=-3.5" width="2" height="1.6">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 640 512" class="signal-meter">
            <rect x= "24" y="384" width="80" height="128" class="signal-bar-1"/>
            <rect x="152" y="288" width="80" height="224" class="signal-bar-2"/>
            <rect x="280" y="192" width="80" height="320" class="signal-bar-3"/>
            <rect x="408" y= "96" width="80" height="416" class="signal-bar-4"/>
            <rect x="536" y=  "0" width="80" height="512" class="signal-bar-5"/>
            <line style="display: none; stroke-width: 40px; stroke: rgb(255, 0, 0);" class="no-signal" x1="64" y1="40" x2="576" y2="424"/>
          </svg>
        </svg>
        <svg id="outdoor-meter-2" class="svg-flow" svg-flow="current-temp,dx=-3.8,dy=-3.5" width="2" height="1.6">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 640 512" class="signal-meter">
            <rect x= "24" y="384" width="80" height="128" class="signal-bar-1"/>
            <rect x="152" y="288" width="80" height="224" class="signal-bar-2"/>
            <rect x="280" y="192" width="80" height="320" class="signal-bar-3"/>
            <rect x="408" y= "96" width="80" height="416" class="signal-bar-4"/>
            <rect x="536" y=  "0" width="80" height="512" class="signal-bar-5"/>
            <line style="display: none; stroke-width: 40px; stroke: rgb(255, 0, 0);" class="no-signal" x1="64" y1="40" x2="576" y2="424"/>
          </svg>
        </svg>
```

I can change the number of bars which are displayed, change the color of the bars, and activate a red slash to indicate loss of signal, all through applying CSS classes to either `outdoor-meter` or `outdoor-meter-2`.

This works well enough, but employs copy/paste repetition of the same SVG code for both meters. There's also one more meter not shown here that uses the exact same code, and now I'm ready to add a fourth meter.

I don't want to keep copying and pasting this same stuff over and over again, but when I try to use `defs` and `symbol` (or `defs` and `g`) like this:

```html
        <defs>
          <symbol id="signal-meter">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 640 512" class="signal-meter">
              <rect x= "24" y="384" width="80" height="128" class="signal-bar-1"/>
              <rect x="152" y="288" width="80" height="224" class="signal-bar-2"/>
              <rect x="280" y="192" width="80" height="320" class="signal-bar-3"/>
              <rect x="408" y= "96" width="80" height="416" class="signal-bar-4"/>
              <rect x="536" y=  "0" width="80" height="512" class="signal-bar-5"/>
              <line style="display: none; stroke-width: 40px; stroke: rgb(255, 0, 0);" class="no-signal" x1="64" y1="40" x2="576" y2="424"/>
            </svg>
          </symbol>
        </defs>
```

...and then access the defined symbol like this:

```html
          <svg id="outdoor-meter" class="svg-flow" svg-flow="current-temp,dx=-5,dy=-3.5" width="2" height="1.6">
            <use xlink:href="#signal-meter"/>
          </svg>
```

...then none of my CSS styling works anymore because a shadow root is created for the `use` content, and the CSS `/deep/` and `::shadow` selectors don't work any more.

The same problem exists if I put the repetitious SVG in an image file and load it up in multiple places that way.

Am I missing something that makes SVG re-use possible without shadow DOM problems getting in my way?

Comment: I was thinking about that as an option, just setting innerHTML of the various elements to that same content, but I was hoping to find a better way.

Comment: If all I needed to style was one color!

Comment: use CSS variables, they work with use like in the duplicate

Comment: While that's a possible work-around, I don't consider this at all a duplicate of that other question, since there's more going on here than changing colors -- display properties too. Those I suppose could be handled with CSS variables as well, but it's still not the same question anymore. Plus, I found an answer that I wanted to post here, but can't now since you closed this question.

Comment: We don't close a questiion as duplicate when it's the *same* question but when at least one asnwer in the target solve the issue of this question and as you stated, the CSS variables trick works here and if it works for color it will logically work with any property since color is a property among many (such conclusion is trivial and I don't think we need a different question for each property). Your answer can still belong to the duplicate target and can be posted there if you have a different idea.

Comment: OK, then, answer posted at other question.